# Migrating 32bit iOS app to 64bit

Tags: ios, ios5

I am migrating my old iOS app code which was build in 32 bit Architecture. Now that Apple has removed support for that in OS11 I have to add support for 64bit. While doing so I am getting following error

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPPShare", referenced from:
```

I have old google plus SDK for sharing that as(filename: GPPShare.h)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is not able to find GPPShare file as your sdk file must not be compatible with 64 bit architecture.Replace it with latest available framework for 64 bit support.